# PDO bindParam() with prepared statement isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok, this is the problem:

This works:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE id = 1");
$STH->execute();
```

This doesn't:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE id = :id");
$STH->bindParam(':id', '1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->execute();
```

What in the world am I doing wrong? It doesn't even throw an exception

Thank you everyone!

Also, this is the whole code

```
<?php
    try {
        $DBH = new PDO("everything is", "ok", "here");

        $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE id = :id");
        $STH->bindParam(':id', '1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH->execute();

        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
            echo $row['nombre']."<br/>";
        }

        $DBH = null;

        echo "Todo salió bien";

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I "can" or I "can't", because this doesn't work either:
    `$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM juegos WHERE id = :id");
    $STH->bindParam(':id', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $STH->execute();`

Comment: You can **not** use parameters on table names. Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: The second parameter of `bindParam` must be a reference. you cant directly pass the value `1`. As an alternative, try `bindValue`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using `bindParam()` the variable is [bound as a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

A string [can't be passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

The following things can be passed by reference:

> Variables, i.e. foo($a)
>
> New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
>
> References returned from functions

Try using [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

```
$STH->bindValue(':id', '1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 8):

PHP `bindParam()` binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement.

The correct way to use `bindParam` is:

```
$id = 1;
$sth = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE id = :id");
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);// use bindParam to bind the variable
                          // ^ PDO::PARAM_INT - the value of the variable $id should be an int
                     // ^ $id - the variable being represented by ':id',
              // ^ :id - represents the variable
              // $id - the variable being represented by ':id',
```

PHP `bindValue()` binds a value to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement.

```
$id=10;
$name=roadkill;
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM juegos
    WHERE id < :id AND name = :name');
$sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);// use bindValue to bind the variable's value
$sth->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);// use bindValue to bind the variable's value
```

The key difference between these two methods is that unlike `PDOStatement::bindValue()`, with `bindParam()` the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that `PDOStatement::execute()` is called.

Answer (score 3):

The value for the `:tabla` parameter will be automatically quoted and escaped by PDO. The query executed would become:

```
SELECT * FROM 'juegos'
```

which is not valid SQL.

Comment: Then why this doesn't work either?
`$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM juegos WHERE id = :id"); $STH->bindParam(':id', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->execute();`

Comment: @arielnmz because you don't have **error reporting** on, as you are supposed to

Comment: What does **error reporting** has to do with the binding of named parameters in prepared statements?

Comment: @arielnmz it does **error reporting** which will report an error to you.

Comment: Ok, so you say that error reporting needs to be "turned on" to make bindParam() work? The question is rather simple and what you say is not useful at all, but thanks for answering anyway

Comment: @arielnmz yes, this question is **indeed** simple if you have error reporting on and google for the error text.

Comment: It wouldn't have hurt to just say *this won't throw an exception, but it will rather write on the logs, turn on error reporting*, but I think sarcasm is more persuading.

Answer (score 1):

do not pass the value directly to BindParam.

```
try {
       // $DBH = new PDO("everything is", "ok", "here");
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');
        $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM statstracker WHERE SrNo = :id");
        $id = 1; // here you should keep it as variable and pass it to param
        $STH->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH->execute();

        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
            echo $row['SrNo']."<br/>";
        }

        $DBH = null;

        echo "Todo salió bien";

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error";
    }
```

Comment: This question already has an answer. No need to add any more.

Comment: Oh, but this person has not marked his question as an answered, i think -1 you give me was for noting, you can see it this question is not answered. offcorse on net there is many slimier question my answer was exact for this one.

Comment: Sorry for the loooooooong delay (I was not used to the side back in '13). The correct answer was: 1. That I can't use prep'd statements to define table or column names and 2. If I use a reference as a parameter I must use `bindParam`, and `bindValue` if I'm using a direct constant of the result of an expression, e.g. `$var."foo"`. But this is a workaround and it's useful too.